# How to set backgroung image in smart device Visual studio 2008?

Tags: c#

Hey 'm using VS2008 smart device WM5.0 pocket PC Emulator to build some mobile Application, which includes background image. I checked form property to set background image. But no use. so help me out.. Thanx